# what is \XXX encode method in javascript

Tags: javascript, python, hex, decode, encode

there is a string like :

```
"\231\122\224\116\046\020\127\275\337\153\163\071\052\266\264\300\024"
```

when I log it in js console, its decoded form is:

```
'\x99R\x94N&\x10W½ßks9*¶´À\x14'
```

I've searched a lot but couldn't find what encode/decode method is, in js its automatically converted. I need to converted this string in python

Comment: This is a hex literal.  Really easy to find info on this.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types

Comment: Scroll down to the *Table: JavaScript special characters* at [String literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#string_literals): `\XXX` = The character with the Latin-1 encoding specified by up to three octal digits `XXX` between `0` and `377`. For example, `\251` is the octal sequence for the copyright symbol. Equivalent Python docs: 
 [String and Bytes literals](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals).